# how can i move properly my code from jscomplete to vscode react?

Tags: reactjs

Hello every body i'm new with the react technologie and i'm working on a project first thing i did an exercice on jscomplete then when i moved to vscode i have some problemes where to put my code i was in one page then i move it and it runs but i dont know probably its the bad way i'm using and now i'm lost can you please help me this is my code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';

const Data = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="cardesign">
      <div style={{
        display: 'inLine-block',
        marginLeft: 10
      }}>
        <div
          style={{
          fontSize: '1.25em',
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        }}>
          {props.id}
        </div>
        <div>
          {props.label}</div>
      </div>
      <button onClick={props.delEvent}>Delete</button>
    </div>
  );
};
//---------------------------------------------------
const DataList = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props
        .data
        .map(data => <Data key={data.id} {...data}/>)}
    </div>
  );
}
// ---------------------------------------------------
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: {
      activities: [
        {
          id: 'A1',
          label: 'Activite 1'
        }, {
          id: 'A2',
          label: 'Activite 2'
        }
      ]
    }

  };

  // ---------------------------------------------------
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        < DataList data={this.state.data.activities}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. What you should do next is separate each part into individual components.

Some changes:

- The components have been converted from `function`s to `class`es. ES6 classes are the preferred way of breaking components down (or at least the way I have seen it done the most).
- The `props` in each class is now referenced by `this.props`.
- The `state` in the `App` component is initialized via a `constructor` method, with a `super` method being called to ensure `React.Component.constructor` gets called.

(note that Code Snippets will not run on StackOverflow, so don't bother `;)`)

#### App.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import DataList from './DataList.js';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {
        activities: [
          {
            id: 'A1',
            label: 'Activite 1'
          }, {
            id: 'A2',
            label: 'Activite 2'
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        < DataList data={this.state.data.activities}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

#### DataList.js

```js
import { Component } from 'react';
import Data from './DataList.js';

class DataList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props
          .data
          .map(data => <Data key={data.id} {...data} />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DataList;
```

#### Data.js

```js
import { Component } from 'react';

class Data extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="cardesign">
        <div style={{
          display: 'inLine-block',
          marginLeft: 10
        }}>
          <div
            style={{
            fontSize: '1.25em',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
          }}>
            {this.props.id}
          </div>
          <div>
            {this.props.label}</div>
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.props.delEvent}>Delete</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Data;
```